# R: Control title size and color in corrplot

Tags: r, size, correlation, title, r-corrplot

Quick question: any possibility of controlling the title size and color in `corrplot`? Thanks

MWE:

```
data(mtcars)
M <- cor(mtcars)
corrplot::corrplot(M, method = "circle", title="some random title here", mar=c(0,0,2,0))
```

Comment: I'd think standard `?par` parameters would work ; try `cex.main` and `col.main`

Comment: you are absolutely right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working, testable example using @user20650's comment.  This will make the title text small and red:

```
data(mtcars)
M <- cor(mtcars)
corrplot::corrplot(M, method = "circle", title="some random title here", mar=c(0,0,2,0), cex.main = 0.5, col.main = "red")
```